# [jenkins_scripts] How to resolve source dependencies in our own ROS-Jenkins?

Tags: ros, jenkins, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm setting up a ROS build farm (we have a number of private repo that we want to test, too; release will will still be submitted via rosdistro). I'm following all the instructions in http://wiki.ros.org/buildfarm and have forked `jenkins_tools` into https://github.com/marc-hanheide/jenkins_tools to deploy `devel` jobs to the jenkins instance. This is all working like a charm, but a problem I can't get my head round is how to resolve source dependencies when submitting "Development Tests" (see http://wiki.ros.org/regression_tests#Development_Tests). The problem is that we have repositories that depend on other not yet released repos (i.e. there are no `.deb` packages generated for them that could be resolved via `rosdep`). What I'd expect for the devel script in https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/jenkins_scripts/blob/master/devel to do is to provide a mechanism to resolve those dependencies as well, but I found now way to solve this with the tools provided. Am I missing something here?

Summarised: *How to build a repository in a Jenkins "Development Test" against other repositories that are also not yet released as debian packages?*

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks,

Marc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190065/%5Bjenkins_scripts%5D-how-to-resolve-source-dependencies-in-our-own-ros-jenkins?/) by [Marc Hanheide](https://answers.ros.org/users/20006/marc-hanheide/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a development test of a repository which depends on other repositories which are not yet released you must list *all* of these repositories in a single invocation of the development test. Then Jenkins will clone all repos into a single workspace and build and test them together.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marc Hanheide](https://answers.ros.org/users/20006/marc-hanheide/) on 2014-08-14**:
right... But the `devel` script (https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/jenkins_scripts/blob/master/devel) currently only supports *one* repository, right? Shall I change it so it supports a full `repo_list` and submit a PR? Also, is there a way to easily resolve package names to repo names?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-08-14**:
For that kind of development test (with multiple repositories at the same time) you must use the `prerelease` script (https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/jenkins_scripts/blob/master/prerelease).